# auth db not working after upgrade

Tags: qgis, postgresql, authentication

OS: MacOS 12.16

I have not been using QGIS for about 18 months so a few months ago I upgraded to 3.24.2. Not sure what the old version was -- 3.16 (or there abouts I think).

When I open a project I am prompted for the password for the auth-db which I give and I tick the box to save to keychain.  I get a yellow banner across the top "Master password could not be save to keychain" and a pop up to enter creds for a layer:

[image]

I click cancel for each layerand then get presented with a list of "Unavailable Layers":

[image]

I then try "edit" on first layer:

[image]

The popup shows

1. definition 'authcfg=tiridb1'
2. Error saying it isn't there
3. Entry in database list saying it is

As usual I appear to be missing something!